# Wide figure in twocolumn output in Plain TeX

Tags: floats, plain-tex

I try to get something which looks like a `figure*` in LaTeX. I have defined `\widetopinsert` and `\endwiedeinsert`. This works but the text on the second column goes into the bottom margin.

```
\catcode`@=11
\raggedbottom

\newdimen\fullhsize
\newdimen\columnsep
\columnsep 1cm
\fullhsize\hsize
\advance\hsize-\columnsep
\divide\hsize\tw@

\def\fullline{\hbox to\fullhsize}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
    \fullline{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\fullline{\the\footline}}

\newif\if@firstcolumn \@firstcolumntrue
\newbox\firstcolumn

\output={\if@firstcolumn \global\setbox\firstcolumn=\columnbox
\global\@firstcolumnfalse
\else
\doubleformat \global\@firstcolumntrue\fi
\ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi}

\def\doubleformat{\shipout\vbox{
\makeheadline
\ifvoid\widetopins\else\fullline{\box\widetopins}\fi
\fullline{\box\firstcolumn\hfil\columnbox} \makefootline}
\advancepageno}

\def\columnbox{\leftline{\pagebody}}

\newinsert\widetopins
\skip\widetopins\z@skip
\count\widetopins=1000
\dimen\widetopins=\maxdimen

\def\widetopinsert{\p@gefalse\par\begingroup\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup\hsize\fullhsize}
\def\endwideinsert{\egroup
\insert\widetopins{\penalty100 % floating insertion
    \splittopskip\z@skip
    \splitmaxdepth\maxdimen \floatingpenalty\z@
    \ifp@ge \dimen@\dp\z@
    \vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\z@\kern-\dimen@}% depth is zero
    \else \box\z@\nobreak\bigskip\fi}\endgroup}

\def\mypicture{\vrule height 100pt depth 40pt width300pt}

\def\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\text\text\text

\widetopinsert
\centerline{\mypicture}
\endwideinsert

\text\text\text\text\text

\bye
```

How can I get the right textheight on the second column?

[image: Plain TeX wide figure]

Comment: Just memorize that `\vsize` from the left column and set it for the right column?

Comment: I think both of the column have  wrong height. Try commenting `\raggedbottom` to see the effect.

Comment: It seems that the second column is too long, but just add `\par` to
your `\text`, for example, after each `amet.` and the first column is
too long as the height of the widetopinsert counts now for the right
column. 
You use the macros of the TeXbook, page 257, and there it is stated:
`In other words, each column should contain its own footnotes and its
own illustrations; we do not have to change the \pagebody macro.`
Therefore to get fullhsize-wide insertions, you must probably
manipulate `\pagebody`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As my comment suggests`\pagebody` must be changed. Currently
both columns are too long. The vbox for the columns are created in
`\pagebody` and in this box the widetopinserts must be handled. Then
the first column isn't to long anymore. So add:

```
\def\pagebody{\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth
   \ifvoid\widetopins \else\unvbox\widetopins\fi \pagecontents}}
```

Of course, the similar lines in `\doubleformat` must be deleted.

The length of the second column must be adjusted. This is best done
in `\output` when the first column is built. (The `\vsize` is reset
after the second column is output.)

But a widetopinsert cannot be handled if it falls in the right
column. And we cannot split the widetopinsert in a left column as the
float went to the next output element and this would be the right
column. In both cases the left column is already created so to change it needs
`\vsplit` and then a completely different approach should be used. See
the macros in Appendix E of the TeXbook, pp. 416--417.

Therefore widetopinserts are only created if `\@firstcolumntrue` is
set; otherwise the material is put aside for the next physical page. The
box `\nxtpgwtibox` keeps the material. It is filled in
`\endwideinsert` if a widetopinsert shall be processed but we are not in the left column or the right column is too
full already. After the page is done the material is placed in a
widetopinsert; see `\doubleformat`.

I added two `\par`s to the `\text` and made some other changes to
clean the code. Note, I have not performed many tests with this code
and there is room for improvement. For example, the code does not
check that the collected widetopinserts need more than a page which is
not allowed as they cannot be split.

Here is the complete code:

```
\newbox\nxtpgwtibox
\newdimen\orgvsize \orgvsize=\vsize

\newdimen\fullhsize \newdimen\columnsep
\fullhsize\hsize \columnsep 1cm

\raggedbottom

\catcode`@=11
\advance\hsize-\columnsep \divide\hsize\tw@

\def\fullline{\hbox to\fullhsize}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
    \fullline{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@\fullline{\the\footline}}

\newif\if@firstcolumn \@firstcolumntrue
\newbox\firstcolumn

\output={\if@firstcolumn 
      \dimen@=\vsize \advance\dimen@ by -\ht\widetopins \advance\dimen@ by -\dp\widetopins
      \global\setbox\firstcolumn=\columnbox \global\@firstcolumnfalse
      \global\vsize=\dimen@
   \else
      \doubleformat \global\@firstcolumntrue
      \global\vsize=\orgvsize\fi
   \ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi}

\def\doubleformat{\shipout\vbox{\makeheadline
   \fullline{\box\firstcolumn\hfil\columnbox}%
   \makefootline}\advancepageno
  \ifvoid\nxtpgwtibox\else
     \insert\widetopins{\penalty100 \floatingpenalty=0
        \box\nxtpgwtibox\nobreak\bigskip}\fi}

\def\columnbox{\leftline{\pagebody}}
\def\pagebody{\vbox to\vsize{\boxmaxdepth=\maxdepth
   \ifvoid\widetopins \else\unvbox\widetopins\fi \pagecontents}}

\newinsert\widetopins
\skip\widetopins\z@skip
\count\widetopins=1000
\dimen\widetopins=\maxdimen

\def\widetopinsert{\par\begingroup\hsize=\fullhsize\setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup}
\def\endwideinsert{\egroup
   \if@firstcolumn
      \dimen@=\ht\z@ \advance\dimen@ by \dp\z@ \advance\dimen@ by 1\baselineskip
      \advance\dimen@ by \pagetotal \advance\dimen@ by -\pageshrink
   \else \dimen@=1.1\pagegoal\fi % no widetopinserts in second column
   \ifdim\dimen@>\pagegoal       % the page is full, no more widetopinserts
      \ifvoid\nxtpgwtibox \global\setbox\nxtpgwtibox=\vbox{\box\z@}%
      \else \global\setbox\nxtpgwtibox=\vbox{\box\nxtpgwtibox
         \nobreak\vskip1\baselineskip\box\z@}\fi
   \else \insert\widetopins{\penalty100 \floatingpenalty=0
      \box\z@\nobreak\bigskip}\fi\endgroup}

\catcode`@=12

\def\mypicture#1{\vrule height 1#10pt depth 4#1pt width3#1#1pt}

\def\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magn
a aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo
duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata
%sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos
et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd
%gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.\par}

\text\text %\text % one more \text moves the 1st widetopinsert to the next page

\widetopinsert
\centerline{\mypicture0}
\endwideinsert

\text

\widetopinsert
\centerline{\mypicture9}
\endwideinsert

\text\text\text\text\text

\bye
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not precize answer, only thought. I see that your text is divide into two parts: the first one contains 3 `\text`s, the second one contains 5 `\text`s, where each `\text` is `\def`ined as `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,... Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.` However, the second part is surrounded with `\widetopinsert` and `\endwideinsert` which open `\vbox` of their own. Maybe, it is worth opening new `\vbox` just before the second part in the same way as it was done before the first one? 
It looks like the vbox for second part is of height that much nore than height of vbox for the first one. Maybe, try to insert someone like `\showthe\vsize` into both parts?