# Defining a figure* equivalent for Plain TeX in multicolumn output

Tags: floats, plain-tex, output-routine

Some time ago I tried to define something like `figure*` for Plain TeX. This resulted in wrong column heights.

(See: [Wide figure in twocolumn output in Plain TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459697/wide-figure-in-twocolumn-output-in-plain-tex))

There was a hint to memorioze the vsize, so I tried this. Please look at the following MWE:

```
% For Plain LuaTeX
\catcode`@=11
\raggedbottom

\newdimen\fullhsize
\newdimen\columnsep
\columnsep 1cm
\fullhsize\hsize
\advance\hsize-\columnsep
\divide\hsize\tw@

\newdimen\fullvsize
\fullvsize\vsize

\def\fullline{\hbox to\fullhsize}
\def\makeheadline{\vbox to\z@{\vskip-22.5\p@
    \fullline{\vbox to8.5\p@{}\the\headline}\vss}\nointerlineskip}
\def\makefootline{\baselineskip24\p@\lineskiplimit\z@
    \fullline{\the\footline}}

% Twocolumn output
\newif\if@firstcolumn \@firstcolumntrue
\newbox\firstcolumn

\output={\ifvoid\widetopins\else%%%%%%%% try to change vsize
    \global\advance\vsize-\ht\widetopins
    \global\advance\vsize-\dp\widetopins\fi
    \if@firstcolumn \global\setbox\firstcolumn=\columnbox
    \global\@firstcolumnfalse
    \else
    \doubleformat \global\@firstcolumntrue\fi
    \ifnum\outputpenalty>-20000 \else\dosupereject\fi}

\def\doubleformat{\shipout\vbox{
    \makeheadline
    \ifvoid\widetopins\else\fullline{\box\widetopins}\fi
    \fullline{\box\firstcolumn\hfil\columnbox} \makefootline}
    \advancepageno
    \global\vsize\fullvsize}% reset \vsize

\def\columnbox{\leftline{\pagebody}}

% like figure* in LaTeX
\newinsert\widetopins
\skip\widetopins\z@skip
\count\widetopins=0 %%%%%%%% to change vsize manually
\dimen\widetopins=.5\vsize

\def\widetopinsert{\p@gefalse\par\begingroup
    \setbox\z@\vbox\bgroup\hsize\fullhsize}
\def\endwideinsert{\egroup
    \insert\widetopins{\penalty100 % floating insertion
    \splittopskip\z@skip
    \splitmaxdepth\maxdimen \floatingpenalty\z@
    \ifp@ge \dimen@\dp\z@
    \vbox to\vsize{\unvbox\z@\kern-\dimen@}% depth is zero
    \else \box\z@\nobreak\bigskip\fi}\endgroup}

\def\mypicture{\vrule height 100pt depth 40pt width300pt}

\def\text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}

\text\text\text

\widetopinsert
\centerline{\mypicture}
\endwideinsert

\text\text\text\text\text

\bye
```

[image]

As you can see in the picture both colums are wrong. Both go into the bottom margin and the second one hast whitespace at the top. What have I done wrong? How can the `\vsize` be changed properly?

Comment: Take a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/source2e?lang=en and steal like crazy.

Comment: I thought about this - but there are so many macros and so many lines of code that I do not know where to begin. I have never written complex output routines.

Comment: Do you have an idea what can be taken from `latex.ltx`?